# set to all NAs a given region in a lat-lon ncfile

Tags: na, netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have the following [netcdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcthyuvriwy1j4r/ncfile.nc?dl=0) which is a global grid with latitude from -90 to 90 and longitude from 0 to 360 degrees.

Let's suppose I would like to set to NAs (or missing values) all the gridpoints (or region) included within latitude -90 to 90 and longitude 20E to 100E.

How can I achieve this?
Is this possible with CDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but one way is the `masklonlatbox` command. Unfortunately, that does the opposite to what you want as it *keeps* the box you define, so you would need to mask the bit to the left and the bit to the right, if you see what I mean.  Luckily cdo handles wrapped longitudes quite well. I tested this out and it worked for me:

```
cdo masklonlatbox,100,20,-90,90 in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: That’ll work. I tend use expr for this and use a conditional using clon and clat to set the variables within a latlon box to something that is than changed to nan. I’ve always felt that CDO’s masking options would be better if they worked the other way round….

Comment: I agree, I'll ask Uwe nicely and maybe they can oblige with an inverse-mask operator...

Comment: amazing. did not know about this operator!